# Simplifying complex numbers in digital signal processing

Tags: complex-numbers

An exercise in my course in digital signal processing has a problem which leads to this expression. I've been calculating it for a while but I can't quite make out how they get to this answer. I have the transfer function $H(z)$
\begin{equation}
H(z)=\frac{\left(1-3z^{-1}\right)\left(1-4z^{-1}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{1}{3}z^{-1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}\right)}\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}\right)=3^2\cdot4^2 \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}\right)
\end{equation}
In order to figure out how they calculated it, I've removed $\left(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}\right)$ from both sides and then calculating it backwards like this
\begin{equation}
\left(1-\frac{1}{3}z^{-1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}\right)\cdot3^24^2=3\left(3-z^{-1}\right)\cdot4\left(4-z^{-1}\right)=12\left(12-7z^{-1}+z^{-2}\right)\neq 1-7z^{-1}+12z^{-2}
\end{equation}
I'm suspecting this is incorrect, as the previous 3 out of 4 exercises has had the wrong answer, but as I don't feel confident with complex numbers I thought maybe I'm doing something wrong. Is there something in my way to calculate this backwards that should be done different due to complex numbers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know but the equality is just plain wrong.

For instance plug values in it $LHS(1)=9$ while $RHS(1)=108$.

Even simpler $LHS(3)=0$ while $RHS(3)$ obviously not zero.

Note also that $LHS(1/3)$ is not defined while $RHS(1/3)$ is defined.

The simplified expression I get is $$\frac {3(z-3)(z-4)}{z(3z-1)}$$

I'm surprised however that in your $H(\omega)$ the term $(1-\frac 14z^{-1})$ cancels between the numerator and denominator, are you sure about your writing ?

Secondly $H(\omega)$ should depend on $\omega$ but you have written it all in $z$, would it be that $\omega=\frac 1z$ ?

Comment: You're correct, I've made a typo. No $\omega$ should be used, it should've been z all along. I corrected my mistake in the post. As far as I've understood it I should be able to cancel $(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1})$ with the numerator as long as I take note of the region of convergence. Either way. Thank you a lot, the answer is wrong. One annoyance less that will bother me this evening.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just plain compute it? It's only a second order polynomial.

$$H(\omega)=\frac{\left(1-3z^{-1}\right)\left(1-4z^{-1}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{1}{3}z^{-1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}\right)}\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1-7z^{-1}+12z^{-2}}{1-\frac{7}{12}z^{-1}+\frac{1}{12}z^{-2}  }\cdot \left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}}{1}\right)$$

And it should be clear what that is already. But if you want to simplify it further multiply both sides of the RHS with the denumerator of the LHS.